# On Facebook can I control which friends appear in my news feed with Friend Lists?

Tags: facebook, friends, friend-list

Facebook's News Feed has always seemed rather arbitrary / random to me. I'd like to control which friends appear in the news feed. Is there a way I can do that using my various friend lists? Alternatives to using friend lists beside explicitly excluding people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll to the bottom of the Most Recent feed and click Edit Options.  You can adjust the friends in the modal dialog that comes up.

[image]

Comment: I was aware of this unfortunately, it is individually based. Interestingly the modal that pop ups is different depending on whether you are viewing *Most Recent* or *Top News*

Comment: Correct.  Top News is the one that controls Friends.  And yes, it is individual based - but as usability goes with Facebook:  take it or leave it. :|

Comment: lol so very true. ;)

Comment: That is the *Most Recent* options dialog.  You can see them both in this answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/how-do-you-unhide-a-friend-on-your-facebook-wall/1983#1983

Comment: Heh, you're right.  My feeds are weird and it likes to randomly change to Top News even when I click Most Recent.  I got confused as to which one I was on.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively  you can  just click the HIDE button next to an item on your feed to hide the person completely or hide just the type of notification. so you can hide all those darn Farmville updates!

Answer (score 0):

In the sidebar on the left, click "Friends" and then click on the name of a friend list.  The news feed will then show only the feed items from friends in that friend list.

This setting is not saved, however.  The next time you go to your news feed it will back to the full feed.